# swig convert the enum in header

Tags: python, c, swig

I am trying to import c header file from python, when using SWIG.(I am a beginner in SWIG). There is only MACROs and enums in the header file. The Macros can be converted successfully but something wrong in enums.

For example, test.h:

```
typedef enum {
  VAL0,
  VAL1,
  VAL2,
  VAL3
}VALS;
```

And then

```
swig -Wall -python -module test test.h
```

Successfully I got a py function and a test_wrap.c file. Strange code appeared:

```
SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "VAL0",SWIG_From_int((int)(VAL0)));
SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "VAL1",SWIG_From_int((int)(VAL1)));
SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "VAL2",SWIG_From_int((int)(VAL2)));
SWIG_Python_SetConstant(d, "VAL3",SWIG_From_int((int)(VAL3)));
```

So VAL0-3 are not defined. Then I got the error VAL0/VAL1/VAL2/VAL3 undeclared when compiled with following command:

```
gcc -c -fpic test_wrap.c -I/usr/lib/python-2.7.5/include/python2.7
```

I think the SWIG noticed it's an enum because I found following code:

```
 static swig_type_info _swigt__p_VALS = {"_p_VALS", "enum VALS *|VALS *", 0, 0, (void*)0, 0};
```

So my question is that why they are not defined? Shouldn't they ve assigned as 0,1,2,3? What should I do?

I failed to find a similar question on stackoverflow. Please tell me if it is duplicated with other questions.

Comment: I vaguely remember bumping into this problem years ago.  I think this is the answer that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20112840/1212725

Answer (score 0):

The [SWIG documentation on enums](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn12) says:

> For enumerations, it is critical that the original enum definition be included somewhere in the interface file (either in a header file or in the %{ %} block). SWIG only translates the enumeration into code needed to add the constants to a scripting language. It needs the original enumeration declaration in order to get the correct enum values as assigned by the C compiler.

Since you called SWIG with a raw header file and the `-module` argument you've not complied with that.

Fortunately the workaround is simple, add the following test.i file:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include "test.h"
```

And then call SWIG with

```
swig -Wall -python test.i
```

Which will be sufficient to make it compile and run as expected. Basically all this does is add `#include "test.h"` into the test_wrap.c file that SWIG generates.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how to use them in python? Yes these variables have values now. However, can I initialize such a enum in python? just like what in C: enum VALS someval = VAL1;

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? There are a few answers already, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502917/168175 https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442110/168175 https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356050/168175, maybe something smarter depending on exactly what control you have and what semantics you want.

Comment: I think none of them works for me... Already I can access the value, however, I need the value to be restrained in a range. In this example, I can assign VAR1-4 to some values but I need that value to be VAR1-4 only. Actually what I need is a enum, or a class. Not only to access the value itself. I am using python2.7.5 now but I can also change the python version so that's not the problem...